# Removing some files in /home increases free space on /?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

Basically I have this simplified file systems:

```
File system           Dim. Usati Disp. Uso% Montato su
/dev/md1               10G  4,0G  5,5G  43% /
/dev/md2              683G  438G  211G  68% /home
```

I am now removing some files within my `/home` dir, and I see that the free space of the first partition increases (`/`)

Is there any correlation between files stored in `/dev/md2` and `/dev/md1` ?
Maybe inodes of `/home` files are stored within `/dev/md1` ?

Comment: _I am now removing some files within my /home dir, and I see that the free space of the first partition increases (/)_ -- Can you provide a 'before' and 'after' picture showing this? The filesystem size of / will change throughout the day, because it includes directories which change often, like /var and /tmp .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that relates the filesystems like that except for possibly symlinks. Hopefully you don't have too many of those from /home to big files in / that you are removing (maybe logs?)

The other potential cause is that files you rm'd from / are being cleared as the last handle on them closes.